# I scrolled out too far in the Blender Shading UI

Tags: blender

I am new to Blender and when i tried to do some shading to the model i accidentally scrolled out too far and now cant find the things i already have done.

[This is how it Looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw0c0.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

There is the 'Frame all' function under 'view' menu which places all nodes into viewport. It has 'Home' key as a shortcut.

Comment: It is greyed out tho